# grep lines in file that consist only of a given string

Tags: regex, grep

I am using the following

`grep -rn "activity" *` to return lines in files of a subdirectory. I get things like:

```
There was no activity
We reported no activity
There was some activity
```

I now want to limit this to lines where the *only* string is the word `activity`. All my searches seem to find limiting the output to the string itself, not the actual line that only consists of the string itself.

Any help would be great!

Comment: `grep -rn "^activity$" *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep can be combined with a concept called regular expressions or re's for short. The following line should do the trick:

`grep -rn "^activity$" *`

**^** - matches the beginning of the line.

**$** - matches the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` has a `--line-regex` flag (shortened into `-x`) that does exactly what you need : when provided, the pattern `activity` will only match whole lines consisting of only "activity".

```
$ echo "There was no activity
We reported no activity
activity" | grep -x activity

activity
```

In your case, using `grep -rxn activity *` should do the trick.